# I want to extend a Verizon Fios Ethernet connection without running long Ethernet cables throughout the house

Tags: networking, internet, cable, fiber, fios

I want a consistent Ethernet connection and do not want long Ethernet cables running throughout the house. I read about the fiber media converters, and I looked at manuals by am unsure if I have the correct ports in my room for this to work.

I have a coaxial cable port in my room. Will this work for using the fiber media converter and what other cables do I need to do but so I can connect it to the fiber media converter?

ETA: I have used powerline adapters before and found the connection was inconsistent, so that's a no-go for me.

Answer (score 2):

Coaxial cable is copper, not fiber. You might want to look at MoCA 2.

There really is no substitute for getting Cat5e or better properly installed in your walls. Power line, MoCA, phone line, and wireless networking all suck compared to real gigabit Ethernet.